# Ruby On Rails - Model's properties and accessors scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help with the scope of instance variables and accessors in a Ruby on Rails model.

Here is a simplification of my model (a blog article).
I've removed the irrelevant parts. Of course it has a set of validations, associations and custom methods.

```
# Table name: articles
#
#  author_url   :string(255)
#  display_date :datetime

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author_url, :display_date

  # callbacks
  before_create :prepare_properties

  # validations
  VALID_URL_REGEX = /\Ahttps?:\/\/.+/i
  validates :author_url, format: { with: VALID_URL_REGEX,
                                message: " can only use http:// or https:// schemes",
                                     if: Proc.new { author_url.include?("://") } }

  private

    def prepare_properties
      display_date ||= Time.now
      author_url.prepend("http://") unless author_url =~ /\Ahttps?:\/\//i
    end
end
```

Now:

- `author_url` is first checked with a validator that ensures that it begins with either `http://`, `https://` or nothing.
- on object creation, this should happen:

  - if `author_url` doesn't already have a (valid) url scheme, `http://` is prepended by default.
  - If the author has not indicated a display_date, `Time.now` is used.

The problem is that the `author_url` accessor works as expected, but the `display_date` one is treated as a local variable scoped within the method. The same happens if I use the callback with a block rather than a separate method.

The only way to make it work, is to use `self.display_date`.

Still, I'm wondering why this happens for just one property and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `self.` to call setters for the current object.

```
self.display_date ||= Time.now
```

Without `self.`, it becomes ambiguous as to whether you want to create a local variable or call the setter, and Ruby chooses creating local variable by default.

> Still, I'm wondering why this happens for just one property and not the other.

Because you're not setting `author_url` to anything; you're just calling a method on it, which is fetched using the getter. The `author_url=` setter is never called.